# Import data from csv file in db2 table

Tags: import, db2

I'm new to db2.  The following:

```
Import from 'c:\temp\devtest.del' of del insert into devtestone(col1,col2)
```

Gives the error:

> 15:13:51 [IMPORT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs] [Error Code: -104, SQL State:
>   42601] DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=Import
>   from 'c:\temp\devtest.del' of del;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;,
>   DRIVER=3.57.82 ... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected,
>   exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]

Comment: It appears you're running the command from a DB2 administration utility other than a plain old DB2CMD command shell. Depending on the program, you may need to switch the backslash characters to forward slashes, and you may need to get rid of the quotes surrounding the input file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMPORT is not an SQL statement, it is a command.

Based on the error message, you're trying to execute the import from some utility that connects to DB2 using JDBC drivers.  If you want to execute the import utility from an application other than DB2 Command Editor / DB2 Command Window, you need to use the ADMIN_CMD wrapper.  This is documented here:  [IMPORT command using the ADMIN_CMD procedure](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023575.html).

Comment: thank you for the response.                                                           When I execute :                                                           CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD ('Import from c:/temp/devtest.del of del insert into devtestone(col1,col2)') I get error as: 15:07:49 [CALL - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs] [Error Code: -3030, SQL State: ] DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-3030, SQLSTATE= , SQLERRMC=sqlofopn -2029060079, DRIVER=3.57.82 ... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]

Comment: As written in the referenced documents:  `the file must exist on the database server.`  If you need to import a file from your workstation, you'll have to use something that understands the IMPORT command: DB2 Command Editor or the DB2 Command Line Processor